# okhttp - Interceptor - Stopping non-fatal exceptions from being logged to Crashlytics

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, interceptor, okhttp

I'm using Retrofit in an android app, and that in turn means im using OkHttp.
I've just gone to Alpha and seeing in my crashlytics report a number of non-fatal exceptions being logged.
All of these are stemming from my okhttp interceptor, and then exceptions being logged all seem to be things that are valid in situations where maybe the network is spotty or if connection drops out etc.

How can I make it so these exceptions are not logged out to crashlytics and thus cluttering up my view of exceptions occuring in the app?

---

Some examples of the exceptions:

```
> Non-fatal Exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException
Connection closed by peer
okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls (RealConnection.java:281)
okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol (RealConnection.java:251)
okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect (RealConnection.java:151)
okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection (StreamAllocation.java:192)
okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection (StreamAllocation.java:121)
okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream (StreamAllocation.java:100)
okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept (ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept (CacheInterceptor.java:93)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept (BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept (RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:120)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
MY_INTERCEPTOR.intercept (AuthenticationInterceptor.java:30)
```

and

```
> Non-fatal Exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException
Read error: ssl=0xdee45cc0: I/O error during system call, Software caused connection abort
okio.Okio$2.read (Okio.java:139)
okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read (AsyncTimeout.java:237)
okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf (RealBufferedSource.java:345)
okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict (RealBufferedSource.java:217)
okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict (RealBufferedSource.java:211)
okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readResponseHeaders (Http1Codec.java:189)
okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept (CallServerInterceptor.java:75)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept (ConnectInterceptor.java:45)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept (CacheInterceptor.java:93)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept (BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept (RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:120)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
MY_INTERCEPTOR.intercept (AuthenticationInterceptor.java:30)
```

This is my interceptors code:

```
@Override
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request request = chain.request();
    Response response = chain.proceed(request);

    if( response.code() == HTTP_AUTHENTICATION_ERROR_CODE ){
        Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_LOGOUT_ACTION);
        mContext.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
    return response;
}
```

I get that I could catch any IOException from the "proceed" call, but wouldnt that mess up OkHttp's proper handling of network errors etc?

Comment: Do the Crashlytics logs still show up without this Interceptor?

Comment: IIRC Crashlytics usually does not log non-fatal exceptions, so it seems like you have a call to `Crashlytics.logException` somewhere in your code base, and you should filter your exceptions there.

Comment: I don't explicitly call log exception in the OkHttp interceptor and this is where the exception is thrown and caught by crashlytics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`Non-fatal Exception` is logged when you call `Crashlytics.logException(Exception)`explicitly in code**

Please Read below information :

`Crashlytics` for Android lets you log caught exceptions in your app's catch blocks! To use this feature, simply add a call to `Crashlytics.logException(Exception)` to your catch block:

```
try {
  myMethodThatThrows();
} catch (Exception e) {
  Crashlytics.logException(e);
  // handle your exception here! 
}
```

All logged exceptions will appear as "non-fatal" issues in the Crashlytics dashboard. Your issue summary will contain all the state information you are use to getting from crashes along with breakdowns by Android version and hardware device.

Comment: I don't explicitly call log exception in the OkHttp interceptor and this is where the exception is thrown and caught by crashlytics.

Comment: then it might me possible that retrofit is calling it internally

Comment: Turned out there was a Timber log occuring at a higher level, but was difficult to trace as the interceptor was the only bit of our code showing in the stack trace. But yes it appears we were calling logexception, thanks for the information

Answer (score 1):

> Crashlytics only stores **Non-fatal Exception** when you use
>     Crashlytics.logException(), see the below code for interceptor , it's throwing 
>     IOException  but exception will not be visible on dashboard on  **Non-fatal 
>     Exception** section , while we not log it.

```
@Override 
public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
Request request = chain.request();

long t1 = System.nanoTime();
logger.info(String.format("Sending request %s on %s%n%s",
    request.url(), chain.connection(), request.headers()));

Response response = chain.proceed(request);

long t2 = System.nanoTime();
logger.info(String.format("Received response for %s in %.1fms%n%s",
    response.request().url(), (t2 - t1) / 1e6d, response.headers()));

return response;
}
```

> so if you want to log the exception under **Non-fatal Exception** , just use Crashlytics.logException();

**and Crashlytics only stores the most recent 8 exceptions in a given app session. If your app throws more than 8 exceptions in a session, older exceptions are lost.**

Answer (score 0):

Just search for `Crashlytics.logException` in your codebase, you will definitely find it somewhere. It is getting logged from there only.

Otherwise **any exception** on  `Response response = chain.proceed(request);` **will cause your app crash :)**

**Wild guess :),** you might be using RxJava & in `onError(throwable: Throwable)` of your subscriber you might be logging it like below

```
override fun onError(throwable: Throwable) {
       Crashlytics.logException(throwable) 
}
```